# Drupal 8, view filter criteria with entity reference field not working

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-8

I have a field called event_author, which is a entity reference to user. The following it in view:

I have the event author field
[image]

I have all the results
[image]

After I add the filter, there is no result any more. It seems it is not entity reference not matching up with text 'author1'
[image]